# Length property not returning the desired value

Tags: javascript, string-length

I tried to get the length of this string:

```
$args[0]-match'\d.*?\/(.*)';$matches[1]
```

using:

```js
console.log("$args[0]-match'\d.*?\/(.*)';$matches[1]".length);
```

I did this in the browser console. It returns 37. However, counting by hand, this string is 39 characters long. Am I missing something or is it a bug in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

backslash character `\` is a special escape character in strings so it doesn't count.

you can make backslashes count by preceding them with another backslash (that is escape the escape character):

```js
console.log("$args[0]-match'\\d.*?\\/(.*)';$matches[1]".length)
```

Answer (score 1):

`\d` is a char, no two.
you have to escape it

```
"$args[0]-match'\\d.*?\\/(.*)';$matches[1]".length
```